Derivation of Evidence lower bound and KL diveregence in VAE. I cannot understand the independence condition.
In the article "An Introduction to Variational Autoencoders" written by Diederik P. Kingma, there are this equation in page 18.
\begin{align}
\log p_{\theta}(x) &= \mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z|x)}[\log p_{\theta}(x)]  \\ 
& = \mathbb{E}_{q_{\psi}(z|x)}[\log [{{p_{\theta}(x,z)}\over{p_{\theta}(z|x)}}]]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q_{\psi}(z|x)}[\log[{{p_{\theta}(x,z)}\over{q_{\phi}(z|x)}}{{q_{\phi}(z|x)}\over{p_{\theta}(z|x)}}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q_{\psi}(z|x)}[\log[{{p_{\theta}(x,z)}\over{q_{\phi}(z|x)}}]] + \mathbb{E}_{q_{\psi}(z|x)}[\log[{{q_{\phi}(z|x)}\over{p_{\theta}(z|x)}}]]
\end{align}
What I cannot understand is the first equation $\log p_{\theta}(x) = \mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z|x)}[\log p_{\theta}(x)]$. Someone say that this equation hold because $p_{\theta}(x)$ and $q_{\phi}(z|x)$ are independent. If they are independent, this hold. But I don't understand why they are independent.
If someone enlight me in this problem, I would really appreciate. Thanks.
